# How do I execute Scrooge from commandline?

Tags: scala, thrift, scrooge

I was able to include scrooge in my SBT project (the scrooge-sbt-plugin in my plugins.sbt as well as the library dependencies in my build.sbt), but I haven't been able to figure out how to execute scrooge from the commandline as listed here http://twitter.github.io/scrooge/CommandLine.html.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the plugin? It's better supported than the CLI.

Comment: I plan on using the plugin primarily.  I just wanted to quickly see the generated code for some thrift files outside of a SBT project. I thought I'd ask since I saw info at the above link about the commandline options, but nothing on how to get it working, and google didn't show anything meaningful.

Comment: I've filed [an issue about this](https://github.com/twitter/scrooge/issues/131). In the meantime you can grab the Scrooge source and point `sbt "project scrooge-generator" "runMain com.twitter.scrooge.Main ..."` at your Thrift files.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party.

@partycoder was indeed right, however a bit more may help those
who like myself aren't too sure.

Assuming your `*.thrift` files are located in `src/main/thrift` simply running `sbt scrooge-gen` will pick up the files and deposit them in `target/src_managed/`.

If your `*.thrift` files are not located in `src/main/thrift` and perhaps in `src/main/resources/thrift`, you can set`scroogeThriftSourceFolder` in you build.sbt using this example:

```
scroogeThriftSourceFolder in Compile <<= baseDirectory {
  base => base / "src/main/resources/thrift/"
}
```

This setting and others can be found [here](https://github.com/twitter/scrooge/blob/develop/scrooge-sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/com/twitter/ScroogeSBT.scala#L108).